# Making retrofit url with following parameters

Tags: android, interface, httprequest, retrofit2

```
https://my/api/call/v1/json/search_thing?parameters={"api_key":"API_KEY","query":{"perpage":50}}
```

For this I made

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("my/api/call/v1/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

But for the interface, How should I fill ???

```
 @GET("???")
    Call<JSONResponse> getJSON();
```

I tried

```
??? = "json/search_thing?parameters={"api_key":"sdfsdf","query":{"perpage":50}}"
```

but did not work.

Basically how should I embed

```
json/search_thing?parameters={"api_key":"API_KEY","query":{"perpage":50}}
```

into my interface

Answer (score 0):

It worked actually there was formatting problem while placing into GET().

```
 @GET("json/search_thing?parameters={"api_key":"sdfsdf","query":{"perpage":50}}")
```

By default when we paste it, android studio adds escape characters for  making the url.